# Is is possible to slipstream DotNet 4 into Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, .net-framework, slipstream

I tried to use nLite but this program is no longer updated. And it seems it has no capability of dealing with dotNet. On my instalation CD there is DOTNETFX folder with version 1.1, but it seems even this old version is not installed with system.

I also read somewhere that it is possible to download dotNet as system update, that is a file with name that begins wih KB.... , so that file could be properly digested by nLite ?

Any help in this matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be possible with [rt7lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/), but there are some more advanced problems with it, you may refer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/273920/slipstream-net-4).

Comment: Well that is also not what I asked about but +1 for mentioning rt7lite, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score -1):

All the frameworks are available at Microsoft's site.
http://www.microsoft.com/net/download.aspx

Comment: That’s not what they asked.

Comment: That is not what I asked about.