# Slipstream .net 4

Tags: .net-framework, slipstream

I am using RT7Lite and need to slipstream .net 4 into my Windows 7 SP1 install.

How do I go about getting the MSU file for .net 4?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no MSU for .NET 4. You'll probably have to run the installer post-install.